# How to implement Secure RSA communication to multiple clients?

Tags: security, encryption, rsa, communication, messaging

The situation: Sender A needs to send messages to B. The data is secured using RSA public key encryption. A och B creates private and public keys and shares the public keys. B runs a client that receives the encrypted messages, and decrypts them using the private key on his machine.

Now B goes to another machine, runs the client, receives messages, but the private key isn't there so he can't decrypt them!

Real world scenario: A chat application, like Skype. B can run Skype on several machines that all can receive the messages.

How can I accomplish this, without transferring the private key? How is this usually handled?

Comment: You have to think about whether the sender knows that there a recipient has multiple machines or not. If not, then the recipient must transfer the private key on each machine.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to avoid, or, if the private key can be encrypted first, in a way that the new client can decrypt it...

Comment: Well, encryption is always a key management issue. You can think of the best strategy in your envisioned system, but it can't be answered generally.

Answer (score 2):

GnuPG does this. You can send a message to many people. Lets break it down. Start with a plaintext message M.

Next create a random key, sk.

Use a symmetric cypher. Aes is a solid choice.

Encrypt M with sk. em = E_sk(M)

So A sends to B and C. A gets Bpub and Cpub, that is, their respective public keys.

Then A encrypts sk with each public key. Header = E_Bpub(sk) & E_Cpub(sk)

A then sends `Header` and `em` to both B and C.

Both B and C use their respective private keys to decrypt their part of `Header` and then when they have `sk`, use `sk` to decrypt the message.

So to answer your question, something like skype or iMessage has multiple public keys for each user and encrypts `sk` with all of them so that any device can decrypt the message.

Hope that helps.

Whatsapp's encryption is based on whisper's paper.

https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/904.pdf
https://whispersystems.org/

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point about using multiple keys to encrypt, but the problem remains that A needs to be aware of all clients.
Suppose that A sends a message to B and C, but those clients are not running,, instead the user boots up his old laptop and installs the client there. Now the message is retrieved but he is unable to read it!

Comment: The pub keys need to be registered somewhere. A central service. Then all client keys are available. The central service wont have access to the message content, just the pub keys.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how to fulfil the requirement.
1) User external "public key" server, which does not participate in conversation but "returns" public key of specified user on request;
2) Use onion routing: say "A" knows "B", but does not know "C". We suppose B knows them all, therefore, the idea is to is B as a proxy for delivering message to C without clear knowledge "A->C". In addition to that, we could use garlic routing to build more complex networks. This is very difficult way of solution.
3) Use one symmetric key (and symmetric algorithm) for chat. It works, but there are problems with revocation: imagine that someone from the chat group no longer trusted. We should at least exclude they from next messages, but as they know the encryption key, he is aware of all next handshakes between participants.
4) Use session key, on which produce a number of ephemeral keys "one-per-message" (see OTR for example). This is more complex solution, but its simplest implementation has the same disadvantage as the method 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it.

Only AES for the regular messages. The same key for each client.
When a new client connects, usa RSA to send the AES key from the sender to the new client using priority messages.  (Recipient sends a request to sender, "give me the AES key, here's my RSA public key") Then process the waiting AES-encrypted messages!

One problem though, the sender must be online to be able to send back the AES key. So when the new client connects he will not be able to accept any messages until sender is online and has been able to respond to the request. But I might be able to live with that.

But... if the SENDER installs a new client on another machine he doesn't have the AES-key anymore...